# Percent Change Across Year-Range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I two tables: Financial Data (FI) and Event Data (ED). I am looking to find a relationship between certain events and financial changes (i.e. Revenue grew an extra 2% after ___ happened).

Example: GOOGLE had an event occur in 2014.. I'd like to compare their revenue (and other metrics) from 2012-2014 and 2014-2016.

I am STRUGGLING to make this comparison or even find one half of the changes. Any help is appreciated

Sample Data:

```
Org Metric  ID  Year    Value
4   Org1    EBITDA  Org1EBITDA2012  2012    3834
5   Org1    EBITDA  Org1EBITDA2013  2013    4141
6   Org1    EBITDA  Org1EBITDA2014  2014    7383
7   Org1    EBITDA  Org1EBITDA2015  2015    9145
8   Org1    EBITDA  Org1EBITDA2016  2016    7503
9   Org1    EBITDA  Org1EBITDA2017  2017    8182
24  Org1    Revenue Org1Revenue2012 2012    87584
25  Org1    Revenue Org1Revenue2013 2013    46794
26  Org1    Revenue Org1Revenue2014 2014    59062
27  Org1    Revenue Org1Revenue2015 2015    58378
28  Org1    Revenue Org1Revenue2016 2016    60257
29  Org1    Revenue Org1Revenue2017 2017    61158
64  Org2    EBITDA  Org2EBITDA2012  2012    20698
65  Org2    EBITDA  Org2EBITDA2013  2013    23161
66  Org2    EBITDA  Org2EBITDA2014  2014    25032
67  Org2    EBITDA  Org2EBITDA2015  2015    22116
68  Org2    EBITDA  Org2EBITDA2016  2016    24964
69  Org2    EBITDA  Org2EBITDA2017  2017    25352
84  Org2    Revenue Org2Revenue2012 2012    67224
85  Org2    Revenue Org2Revenue2013 2013    71312
86  Org2    Revenue Org2Revenue2014 2014    74331
87  Org2    Revenue Org2Revenue2015 2015    70074
88  Org2    Revenue Org2Revenue2016 2016    71890
89  Org2    Revenue Org2Revenue2017 2017    76450
```

Current Code:
My current code shows me adding in specific columns in each table to accommodate for the different years (and my plan was to merge the tables), but this cannot be the right way to do this..

```
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import numpy as np
from datetime import date

# Pull in Data
path = r"C:\Users\xx.xx\desktop\Python\PyTest\PyFIvID.xlsx"
path2 = r"C:\Users\xx.xx\desktop\Python\PyTest\PyEventsvID.xlsx"
sheet = 'Adjusted Data'
fi = pd.read_excel(path,sheet_name=sheet)
tgps = pd.read_excel(path2,sheet_name=sheet)

metric = 'Revenue'
tgps.replace(['Outlier','No Data'],float('NaN'),inplace=True)
fi.replace(['Outlier','No Data'],float('NaN'),inplace=True)

tgps['ID-1'] = tgps['CapIQ'] + metric + (tgps['Year']-1).map(str)
tgps['ID-2'] = tgps['CapIQ'] + metric + (tgps['Year']-2).map(str)
tgps['ID-3'] = tgps['CapIQ'] + metric + (tgps['Year']-3).map(str)
tgps['ID+1'] = tgps['CapIQ'] + metric + (tgps['Year']+1).map(str)
tgps['ID+2'] = tgps['CapIQ'] + metric + (tgps['Year']+2).map(str)
tgps['ID+3'] = tgps['CapIQ'] + metric + (tgps['Year']+3).map(str)

fi['ID-1'] = fi['CapID'] + metric + (fi['Year']-1).map(str)
fi['ID-2'] = fi['CapID'] + metric + (fi['Year']-2).map(str)
fi['ID-3'] = fi['CapID'] + metric + (fi['Year']-3).map(str)
fi['ID+1'] = fi['CapID'] + metric + (fi['Year']+1).map(str)
fi['ID+2'] = fi['CapID'] + metric + (fi['Year']+2).map(str)
fi['ID+3'] = fi['CapID'] + metric + (fi['Year']+3).map(str)

merg = tgps.merge(fi,on='ID')
merg.set_index(['ORG'], inplace=True)

path3 = r"C:\Users\xx.xx\desktop\Python\PyTest\PyCapIQ5.xlsx"
writer = ExcelWriter(path3)
fi.to_excel(writer,'FI Data')
tgps.to_excel(writer,'TGPS Results')
merg.to_excel(writer,'Merged')
writer.save()
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of what is the result should be?? And Also could you please explain the meaning of each column in your sample data?

Comment: The sample data is organized by Company, FI Metric, KEY (unique ID), Fiscal Year, Value of Metric. If Google was Org1, the output would be the following:  (59062 - 87584)/87584 = -0.32 and (60257 - 59062)/59062 = 0.02